# Изменить настройки виджета - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть некий плагин, который может исключать страницы из виджета, что позволяет создавать уникальные меню.

В базе данных, данный виджет держит информацию в таком виде

**Имя таблицы:** widget_pages

```
Array ( [3] => Array ( [title] => Машины [sortby] => post_title [exclude] => 91, 113, 117, 119, 115 )
Array ( [4] => Array ( [title] => Мотоциклы [sortby] => post_title [exclude] => 91, 113, 117, 119, 115 )
```

Немного почитав мануалы, получил массив таким образом

```
<?php 
$opt = get_option('widget_pages'); 
print_r($opt); 
?>
```

Далее, я начал читать про **add_options** функцию, и чесно говоря не понял как она работает, дело в том что моя задача, **добовлять/удалять** значение из

```
post_title [exclude]
```

Как это сделать програмно с помощью фунций самого wordpress ?

Comment: `get_option('widget_pages')` не может возвращать ничего из таблицы widget_pages. Потому что `get_option('widget_pages')` возвращает значение поля option_value записи, у которой поле option_name= widget_pages из таблицы wp_options.

Comment: я ошибся, верно говорите. Но как мне правильно обновлять значения ? к примеру добавить/удалить из exclude, id страницы ? Просто когда сайт был мелким, можно было без труда делать руками, но когда айди стало больше, искать их стало целой рутинной работой...

Comment: Трудно сказать, не видя примеров виджетов и того, что вам нужно сделать. Можно фильтровать вывод виджетов с помощью фильтра 'widget_text'. Но не уверен, что вам именно это надо.

Comment: Только что подумал, но это решение будет наверно костылем ? Так как мы получаем многомерный массив в переменную $opt, то может пустить ее в обработку по замене текста в многомерном массиве ? а потом с помощью update_option запихнуть обратно.. но я думаю данное решение будет костылем.. думаю должен быть проще вариант.

Comment: Почему трудно, смотрите мы получаем значения option_value сразу в массиве с помощью get_option, теперь осталось сделать хитрый - правильный update_option. Проблема еще заключаеться в том, как правильно обновлять, т.е изменять именно определенной значение, а не обрабатывать весь массив целиком и пихать обратно. Думаю если узнать как, то проблема решена.

Comment: Вы никак не сделаете "хитрый" update_option, потому что одна опция - одно поле. Вам надо сделать get_option, развернуть многомерный массив, исправить его и вернуть в базу посредством update_option. Все так и работают с опциями, в которых содержатся сериализованные данные.

Comment: Понял, пришла вторая идея, сделать опцию, некий чекбокс, удалить, добавить, при выборе которого в foreach происходит то или инное действие, т.е перебираем (удаляем, добовляем) складываем обратно, обновляем. Пока что только так додумаля. Спасибо

Comment: Если получится сделать, обновлю вопрос, с готовой функцией.